# How do you denote functions inherited by a product space?

Tags: functions, tensor-products, product-space, direct-product, map-projections

Given a map $f:A\to B$, define the map $p_n(f):A^n\to B^n$ as $p_n(f)(a_1,...,a_i)=(f(a_1),...,f(a_i))$. Equivalently, you could say given $f$, $p_n(f)$ is such that $\mathrm{proj}_a\circ p_n(f)=f\circ \mathrm{proj}_a$.

**My question is:** is there a notation for $p_n(f)$ where we don't have to go through the the hassle of explaining what it is? I thought maybe some kind of tensor product or direct sum of $f$ would do the trick but I don't think they define it in the way I need.

I guess you could write $p_n(f)=(f(\cdot),...,f(\cdot))$ but I don't find that very asthetically pleasing. Is there another notation that could do this?

**Note:** if it helps, I'm working with the specific case where $f$ is invertible.

Comment: I think your "equivalent" version is about the best that can be done. Could fancy it up talking about co-diagonal maps or something, but it wouldn't necessarily communicate more effectively. For that matter, writing the formula requires no common understanding of fancier terminology, etc. There are toooo many slightly different contexts for there to be an easy, robust standard for this, I think.